# c# linq contains operator

Tags: c#, xml, linq, windows-phone-7, contains

I am developing at WP7 c# linq and XML. This query below doesn't work (Cannot convert type 'bool' to 'string'). I need some easy usable equivalent to SQL Like operator. Operator == works well

```
var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("Row")
                         where ((string)query.Element("Names").Value.Contains("Joh"))
                        select new Kalendars
                        {
                            myDate = (int)query.Element("Date"),
                            myMonth = (string)query.Element("Month"),
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change:

```
((string)query.Element("Names").Value.Contains("Joh"))
```

to:

```
query.Element("Names").Value.Contains("Joh")
```

or you might be able to use [**SqlMethods.Like**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like.aspx)

Comment: query.Element("Names").Value.Contains("Joh")
 -- now i have "NullReferenceException"

Comment: where SqlMethods.Like(query.Element("Names"), "Joh") causes "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods.Like(string, string)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: If you're getting a `NullReferenceException`, that means that either there is no "Names" element or the "Names" element is empty.  It would help us if you added a sample of your XML to your question.

Comment: Names element is not empty, because query works well with == operator:
 
`where (string)query.Element("Names") == "John, George"`

Comment: You were completely right. Problem was in XML absent values. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You could try casting the Element to string, instead of the result of Contains:

```
where ((string)query.Element("Names")).Contains("Joh")
```